# Trying interpolation with my GeoTIFF file using gdal but not working

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-translate

I was trying interpolation using gdal_translate but the results are always the same for all interpolations be it nearestneighbour, bilinear, cubic, etc. No change in file size and no change in output as well.

fileLink: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ndq56ykPGQkJpbz9-4laCGWIezMb8z8d/view?usp=sharing

Its a single band image with resolution 5kx5k. The file size is around 80mb

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -b 1 -r bilinear allchdr5k.tiff allchdr5k_bilinear.tiff
gdal_translate -of GTiff -b 1 -r cubic allchdr15k.tiff allchdr15kcubic.tiff
```

The above and all other interpolations are giving me the same results.

Am i doing this right? As @user30184 said that gdal translate doesnt do interpolation then what else should i go for?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] your question to focus on one issue.

Answer (score 0):

Gdal_translate does not interpolate if it does not need to but it can just copy the pixels. Change the output size `-outsize` or target resolution `-tr` to trigger resampling. Or use gdalwarp and warp into some other coordinate system.

If you want to apply a smoothing filter it can be done with GDAL but in a somewhat tricky way. Read about kernel filters from https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html#kernelfilteredsource.